# How to connect from JavaScript to SignalR in Cross domain?

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr, signalr.client

I have an signalR application which listen from different clients such as C#, JavaScript later we may extend it for other technologies. My signalR server is in console Application. right now I created .net client which are successfully connected to server. I tried a lot to write a javascript client but i didn't succeed. please help me to fix it.

1. I created server.Js file by running the command `signalr.exe ghp /path:` and include it in Js page

2. I am using 2.0.1 version for `Owin` and `SignalR`

3. tried with server URL http://127.0.0.1:8088/signalr and http://127.0.0.1:8088

Here is my server code

```
[assembly: Microsoft.Owin.OwinStartup(typeof(Program.Startup))]   
    namespace SignalRServer
    {
        internal class Program
        {
            private static IDisposable SignalR;

            private static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string url = "http://127.0.0.1:8088/signalr";
                SignalR = WebApp.Start(url);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            public class Startup
            {
                public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
                {
                    app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                    app.MapSignalR();
                }
            }

            [HubName("MyHub")]
            public class MyHub : Hub
            {
                public void Send(string name, string message)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{name}:{message}");
                    Clients.All.addMessage(name, message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My JS Client Code

```
var con = $.hubConnection('http://127.0.0.1:8088');  
   alert(con);
      var hub = con.createHubProxy('MyHub');          
      con.start().done(function () {
      alert('Now connected, connection ID=' + connection.id);
  });
      hub.invoke('Send');
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: while(con.state == $.signalR.connectionState.connecting){}
I added this line to JS and seems the state never changes always on connecting state